# AWS Lambda: Cannot proceed callback in an 'Error'

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, amazon-lex

I'm trying to invoke a lambda function. The function works when the data is available resolve(), but when there is an error, it does not proceed with the callback, and just gives me an error.

```
lambda.invoke({
        FunctionName: 'cognitoFunction',
        Payload: JSON.stringify({
            email: slots.Email
        })
    }, function(err, data) {
        if(err) { // Does not work

            callback(close3(sessionAttributes, { "contentType": "PlainText", "content": "ERROR" }));

        }
        else { // This part works
            callback()
        }
    });
```

> "errorType": "DependencyFailedException",
>
> "errorMessage": "Invalid
>   Lambda Response: Received error response from Lambda: Unhandled"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. The error goes into ***'data'***, not into ***'error'*** :

```
lambda.invoke({
        FunctionName: 'functionName',
        Payload: JSON.stringify({
            email: slots.Email
        })
    }, function(error, data) {
        if(error){
            callback(...)
        }
        else {
            data = JSON.parse(data.Payload);
            if(data.errorMessage) { // The error output is in here
                callback(close(sessionAttributes, { "contentType": "PlainText", "content": data.errorMessage }));
            }
        }
    });
```